# How to feed with 2 or more inputs a Neural Network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to feed a Neural Network with more than one input (using the Matlab tool Box).

If I declare the input vector like `P = [1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4]`, the target as `T = [1 2 3 4]` and then the network as `net = newff(P,T,1);`, when I look at the network parameters it says `numInputs: 1`, while in my mind the number of inputs should be 3 (one for each row).

My question is: how to feed the network with 3 separated inputs?

Thanks in advance,
Regards
G.B.

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish between the following parameters:

1. The dimension of the input vector to the neural network. In your example, the first layer has one input vector of dimension `4`. This parameter is called `R` in Matlab's documentation.
2. The number of different inputs to the network, which is how many **sets** of vectors are input to the network. From the [Neural Network Toolbox doc's](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/network2.html#23709):

   > **net.numInputs**
   >   This property defines
   >   the number of inputs a network
   >   receives. It can be set to 0 or a
   >   positive integer. **Clarification**: The
   >   number of network inputs and the size
   >   of a network input are not the same
   >   thing. The number of inputs defines
   >   how many sets of vectors the network
   >   receives as input. The size of each
   >   input (i.e., the number of elements in
   >   each input vector) is determined by
   >   the input size (net.inputs{i}.size).
   >   Most networks have only one input,
   >   whose size is determined by the
   >   problem.
3. The number of samples of the input which is given to the network. In your example, you have 3 samples of 4-dimensional vectors.

With this in mind, if you meant to feed the network with 3 samples, then your code is ok. If, on the other hand, you really need **3 different sets** of inputs, you can manually change the `numInputs` parameter in your network, or you can create a custom network:

```
net = network(numInputs,numLayers,biasConnect,inputConnect, layerConnect,outputConnect);
```

with the number of inputs `numInputs` as you need, but them you need to customize it yourself. You can read more about it here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/network.html#667825

Comment: Thanks for your help Itamar, just a clarification. I thought that a input instance was placed by column. 
For example `1;1;1;1` is an input instance of 4 elements (ie the input size is 4), while the outputs are placed by row.

Comment: Input instance/sample **is** by column, so each column is indeed an input instance. But what the network parameter `numInputs` means, **isn't** 'input dimension' nor is it 'number of input samples'.

Comment: Ok, now I see the confusion: In your question, your matrix is 4x4. If you want 3 samples of 4 elements each, your input should be 4x3.